# assigning a css font family with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I have a website, in which I have the following code for changing the whole fonts in the website:

```
<script>
$("docoment").ready(function(){
        $("*").css("fontFamily", "Tahoma");

    }

)
```

However, I want to assign a family of fonts to the website, such that if a client does not have one font, he/she can use the second or the third one. I have used the following code, but it does not work:

```
<script>
$("docoment").ready(function(){
        $("*").css("fontFamily", "Tahoma,Times New Roman,Arial");

    }

)
```

Comment: You have spelled document wrong in your jquery there. Is this a typo or is that actually in your live code?

Comment: Unrelated to the question but you are assigning this property on ALL the elements of your page. I would suggest you to narrow this selector.

Answer (score 6):

Reason being:

1. It is `document` not `docoment`.
2. It is just `document` not `"document"`.
3. If `fontFamily` didn't work, you may need to use `font-family`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").css("fontFamily", "Tahoma,Times New Roman,Arial");
}
```

You can also use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").css("font-family", "Tahoma,Times New Roman,Arial");
}
```

**Important Note**

> ***On a heavier note:*** Please do not execute the above code, which makes `style="font-family: Tahoma,Times New Roman,Arial"` on all the elements, which might slow down and eventually crash the browser!